# dependence factors of openmp

Tags: c, openmp

Is the execution time for OpenMP is dependent on the number of iterations or on the size of the structural block? I wanted to optimize the functions using Pocket-shpinx but after the completion of the program, it was seen that it was consuming more time. Can any one please explain me where is my fault

Thanks in advance.

Am attaching just a small part of the code

```
static int32
get_scores_4b_feat_4(s2_semi_mgau_t * s, int i,
                     int16 *senone_scores, uint8 *senone_active,
                     int32 n_senone_active)
{
    int32 j, xyz;
    uint8 *pid_cw0, *pid_cw1, *pid_cw2, *pid_cw3;
    uint8 w_den[4][16];

    /* Precompute scaled densities. */
    for (j = 0; j < 16; ++j) {
        w_den[0][j] = s->mixw_cb[j] + s->f[i][0].score;
        w_den[1][j] = s->mixw_cb[j] + s->f[i][1].score;
        w_den[2][j] = s->mixw_cb[j] + s->f[i][2].score;
        w_den[3][j] = s->mixw_cb[j] + s->f[i][3].score;
    }

    pid_cw0 = s->mixw[i][s->f[i][0].codeword];
    pid_cw1 = s->mixw[i][s->f[i][1].codeword];
    pid_cw2 = s->mixw[i][s->f[i][2].codeword];
    pid_cw3 = s->mixw[i][s->f[i][3].codeword];

         #pragma omp parallel for\
        shared(s,w_den,senone_active,senone_scores)


    for ( j = 0; j < n_senone_active; j++) {
        int n = 0;
         #pragma omp parallel for\
                reduction(+:n)\
                firstprivate(senone_active)
        for(xyz = 0;xyz<=j;xyz++)
                n = senone_active[xyz] + n ;
        int tmp, cw;

        if (n & 1) {
            cw = pid_cw0[n/2] >> 4;
            tmp = w_den[0][cw];
            cw = pid_cw1[n/2] >> 4;
            tmp = fast_logmath_add(s->lmath_8b, tmp, w_den[1][cw]);
            cw = pid_cw2[n/2] >> 4;
            tmp = fast_logmath_add(s->lmath_8b, tmp, w_den[2][cw]);
            cw = pid_cw3[n/2] >> 4;
            tmp = fast_logmath_add(s->lmath_8b, tmp, w_den[3][cw]);
        }
        else {
            cw = pid_cw0[n/2] & 0x0f;
            tmp = w_den[0][cw];
            cw = pid_cw1[n/2] & 0x0f;
            tmp = fast_logmath_add(s->lmath_8b, tmp, w_den[1][cw]);
            cw = pid_cw2[n/2] & 0x0f;
            tmp = fast_logmath_add(s->lmath_8b, tmp, w_den[2][cw]);
            cw = pid_cw3[n/2] & 0x0f;
            tmp = fast_logmath_add(s->lmath_8b, tmp, w_den[3][cw]);
        }
        senone_scores[n] += tmp;

    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Edit the question  and show the relevant code.

Comment: In your first pragma add private(xyz).  Remove the second prama (only parallelize the outermost loop).  Finally, when you write to `senone_scores[n]` if two threads have the same n you will get a race condition.  Additionally, if two threads write to the same cache-line you will have false sharing.  You may need to make private versions of `senone_scores` and then merge them.